# Do all Android devices include Android Browser?

Tags: hardware, android, mobile-devices

(e.g. the Chrome browser for Android)

Talking about factory defaults here, not what users can install later.

(Sorry if this is a stupid question, I just can't find an answer anywhere)

Comment: Yes, it includes a Android Webkit's Browsers and it is a part of android OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically consumer facing Android devices do come with the browser. It is part of the core platform.

However, there is nothing stopping a manufacturer from removing the Browser for whatever reason. For example, that Android powered watch will not come with a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as it's part of Android OS.